# Accessing count of images in directory in CDN

Tags: cdn

I am using CDN for hosting all the images, I have a folder of sub-folders in which each sub folder has a different number of images. Given this situation, how do I actually grab the number of images in each folder in  php script?

I am using codeiginter for this project.

Previously I was using this script as the images were not hosted on CDN yet.

> count(glob('http://www.mywebsite.com/folders/sub-folder/*'));

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: are you also using a database to store image names for each image??

Comment: nope not at all. That is a good idea actually. I would like this process to be automated. If I upload the images to CDN, I still have to run a script to count the images and do an insertion of each image names to the database. We will have to waste time doing this every month then, or even maybe every week, because there are new images to be uploaded every week or so.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood your last comment, but if you write a code once that saves images to db every time images get uploaded, and then you write once code to count how many rows in db you have, it makes it pretty much automated. All you have to do is upload photos.

Answer (score 1):

You have directory helper in CI, thats read folder and put all in array, use it like this

```
$this->load->helper('directory');

$data['files']= directory_map('./folders/sub-folder');
```

And simple count array members in view

```
$number=count($files);
```

Or Just

```
echo count(directory_map('./folders/sub-folder'));
```